# How to import SQL table data to Redis Cache?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, azure, redis, azure-sql-database

I have following table `MYTestTable`

```
ID  Name Location
1   aaa  IND
2   bbb  US
3   ccc  UK
```

Now I want to save this data to Redis Cache (with same table structure ), How can I do this so?

> I tried google but I only found examples with `Key-Value Pair` :(
>
> Can any one give me good thread which is useful , Thanksin advance.
> using LINQ to SQL for database connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redis **is not** a Relational Database and that's the reason why you only found Key-Value examples.

> Redis **is** an open source, BSD licensed, advanced key-value cache and store. It is often referred to as a data structure server since keys can contain strings, hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets, bitmaps and hyperloglogs. *in http://redis.io/*

So if you still want to store the data, knowing that [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) does not provide SQL syntax for queries this is one way to do it:

1. Find what is your key
2. Use the key(s) as the [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) key and *stringify* the value

**Example:**

```
> set mytest.1 "aaa : IND"
OK
> set mytest.2 "bbb : US"
OK
> set mytest.3 "ccc : UK"
OK
```

To retrive the values, just `GET` the key:

```
> get mytest.2
"bbb : US"
```

As you can see there is no concept of column, and although you could create an entry for those, if you get that far, I would re-evaluate if [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) is really what you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: great help is there anything like a collection to store in `Redis` instead of using different different `key value`, any thing like dictionary in c# so i can create one `mytest` add 3 key value pair in it

Answer (score 1):

Redis supports keys which keys can contain strings, hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets, bitmaps and hyperloglogs. For more info you can go to redis.io

You can serialize string or objects and store them in Redis. See this article about storing information from your database in a Redis Cache
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/05/mvc-movie-app-with-azure-redis-cache-in-15-minutes/

Comment: thanks for the info , in my case what you suggest how can I do so ? any thread :)

Comment: Look at the blog post I mentioned in my answer. It has a sample in it which you can follow.